# InvalidKeyException: invalid key format when reading EC Private Key from PEM file in Java

Tags: java, private-key

I'm trying to create a private key object from a given .pem file. The file has this structure:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
...............................
...............................
...............................
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am attempting to create the private key object with this code:

```
public static String getKeyFromFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    String key = new String(keyBytes);

    return key;
}

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, NoSuchProviderException {
    String privateKeyPEM = getKeyFromFile("MY_FILE.pem");

    privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replace("-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replaceAll("\n", "");
    privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM.replaceAll(" ", "");

    byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKeyPEM.getBytes();
    String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKeyBytes);
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);

    EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedString);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);

    return privKey;
```

Upon running this method, I receive this error:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
```

I am able to parse the text and strip away any unwanted characters just fine, but I'm not able to create the private key object. I am able to generate a public key object from a similar .crt file using very similar methods. I want to be able to do this solely within Java and no openssl. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes,  parsing the text and keeping it as is gives the same issue. Just using a hard coded string with the .pem contents does as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not properly decode the base64 data:

`privateKeyPEM` contains the String data between the `BEGIN` and `END` data (which is base64 encoded).

Your code does the following:

```
byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKeyPEM.getBytes();
// privateKeyBytes now contains the base64 encoded key data

String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKeyBytes);
// encoded String contains now the base64 encoded data of the base64 encoded key data

byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
// decodedString is not the base64 encoded data of your key data
```

Why are you encoding the data base64 and then in the next line decoding it - both steps together are just useless.

What you really need is to apply the base64 decode one time onto privateKeyPEM:

```
byte[] keyData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);
EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyData);
```

If the base64 decode fails then your base64 data is invalid - most likely because of contained spaces or `\r`.

Comment: Oh, hadn't even realized I was doing that! After decoding the initial data and replacing any spaces or returns, I get the error "java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     01"

Comment: Which Java version do you use? If it does not work using Java 10 the only chance I see is to use BouncyCastle.

Comment: I'm currently using Java 8.

Comment: If it says "BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY" then it's not PKCS8. It some other format that will need to be converted to PKCS8. PKCS8 pem files have the header "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" without the "EC" bit.